# Create Dynamic Excel path to read in Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Happy NYE! Hopefully this is the last question of the year from me. I am trying to create a dynamic excel path for python to extract various excel files based on the date, type parameters, etc.

I have created below parameters which I can change base on the file I am trying to retrieve:

```
date = input() [assign '201912']
type = input() [assign 'abc']
```

I am trying to figure out a way to incorporate these into the file directory I am asking python to read such that it returns the same result as below:

```
import pandas as pd
sheet=pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Information\Management\201912\abc\abc Template 201912.xlsm')
```

Have tried few different ways but cant seem to get it to work. Any suggestions on this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I tried sheet=pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Information\Management\%s\abc\abc Template 201912.xlsm'%date) which works but how would you go about this if you have more than one value to replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format it with the `%` sign like in Python 2 (not recommended):

```
path = r'C:\Information\Management\%s\%s\%s Template %s.xlsm' % (date, type, type, date)
```

The Pythonic way in Python 3 is to use `str.format`:

```
path = r'C:\Information\Management\{}\{}\{} Template {}.xlsm'.format(date, type, type, date)
```

Or with named parameters:

```
path = r'C:\Information\Management\{date}\{type}\{type} Template {date}.xlsm'.format(date=date, type=type)
```

Starting with Python 3.6, you can also use f-strings:

```
path = f'C:\\Information\\Management\\{date}\\{type}\\{type} Template {date}.xlsm'
sheet = pd.read_excel(path)
```

Comment: thanks so much for answering! I am using python 3 unfortunately. What would be the corresponding code to make it work ?

Comment: You get find out the exact version of Python you are using by typing `python --version` in the command line. BTW, 3.6 is Python 3